# Is $C^\infty(M, V) $ isomorphic to $C^\infty(M) \otimes V$?

Tags: general-topology, tensor-products

Let $M$ be  a smooth manifold and $V$ be a real vector space . Let's Consider the space $C^\infty(M, V)$ of smooth functions from $M$ to $V$. Can we identifiy the space $C^\infty(M, V)$  with the space $C^\infty(M) \otimes V$ ? And if yes,  why this is true ?

Comment: what is $C^{\infty}(M)$ ????????????

Comment: Ooh my god, I'm sorry for that, I just realize what I've written. Actually my question is somehow in a larger context and I was trying to simplify it!  I'll edit my question.

Comment: Infinitely differentiable does not make sense for arbitrary topological spaces $M.$

Comment: More than one question mark is unnecessary, and that many question makes might as well be ALL CAPS, and reads as rude. If you need to reach the character limit, try `${}{}{}{}{}$` @AbdelmalekAbdesselam

Comment: thank you @Thomas Andrew for correcting me. I'll fix my mistake.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I don't think I was rude, but emphatic yes, in my alerting the OP to something that didn't add up in the original version.

Comment: You need a topology on $V$ to make sense to continuity of a function $M\to V$. Maybe you meant $V$ finite dimensional, ie. $V=\Bbb{R}^n$ with its natural topology? Otherwise it is not completely obvious to me what is the topology implied by $C^\infty(M)\otimes V=C^\infty(M,V)$. If $M$ is not compact and $V$ is infinite dimensional it should be wrong in every case.

Comment: @reunis, thank you for your comment! Actually yes the manifold M I have is compact (it's a compact Lie group) and the vector space I have is finite dimensional (it's the space of differential forms on its Lie algebra: $\wedge \mathfrak{g}^*$ ). So in this case do I get  the identification I'm looking for ?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam It doesn’t matter if you think it is rude, or if you intend it to be rude. Lots of question marks at the end of a question implies a tone of disbelief that you have to ask the question. Whether you intend that or not. I never accused you of rudeness, only that appearance of rudeness. “Emphasis?” That can also appear rude.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I guess we can put this to rest. I apologized below to asma

Comment: No worries@Abdelmalek Abdesselam! And thank you to both you and Thomas Andrews for contributing to answer my question.                                                               Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a topology on $V$ to make sense to continuity of a function $M\to V$. So I assume $V$ is a real topological vector space.

Then we have the natural identification $$C^\infty(M)\otimes V= \{f\in C^\infty(M,V), \dim span(\{ f(p),p\in M\})<\infty\}$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^J \phi_j \otimes v_j \mapsto \qquad (p\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^J \phi_j(p) v_j)$$

When $V$ is finite dimensional (there is a unique real topological vector space structure on it) then $C^\infty(M)\otimes V$ is clearly the whole of  $C^\infty(M, V)$.

When $V$ is infinite dimensional and $M$ is not compact, no, because we can take infinitely many non-zero compactly supported smooth functions $\phi_j\in C^\infty(M)$ with disjoint supports, with $\bigcup supp(\phi_j)$ closed, and $\dim span(\{v_j\})=\infty$ then  $p\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^\infty\phi_j(p)v_j$ is not in $C^\infty(M)\otimes V$.

When $V$ is infinite dimensional and $M$ is compact, it shall depend on $V$'s topology.

Comment: @reunis, this is very helpful! Thank you so much.

Comment: I think reuns is referring to the strict understanding of $\otimes$ as the algebraic tensor product. When $V$ is an infinite dimensional TVS one rather uses a completion $\widehat{\otimes}$ of that algebraic tensor product and, following up on reuns' answer, this is how you get the whole of $C^{\infty}(M,V)$. The problem is there are many possible completions. But since $M$ is compact, $C^{\infty}(M)$ is nuclear and these completions should be the same, if I remember correctly. See the book by Treves, Ch. about nuclear spaces.

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam, thank you so much for your comment! this was very interesting,  and thank you for the reference as well.

Comment: @asma: You're very welcome and I apologize to you if I came out as rude earlier with my multiple question marks. It was certainly not intended to be rude.